# 4200 - SQL0104 - Token was not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, ibm-midrange

> ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104
>   - Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE.

This is My Code, I want to display the Table Records to Data Grid View in VB from AS400

```
Sub ShowAS400()
    Call takeconnectionas400()
    conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    adapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("select * from PYLEAVE (PTMIFLIB)", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    adapter.Fill(ds, "PYLEAVE (PTMIFLIB)")
    DGVAS400.DataSource = ds.Tables("PYLEAVE (PTMIFLIB)")
    DGVAS400.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What´s the name of your table? `select * from PYLEAVE (PTMIFLIB)` is not valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to modify your query like this

```
  select * from PTMIFLIB.PYLEAVE
```

or like this

```
  select * from PTMIFLIB/PYLEAVE
```